# Yii gii russian text not visible

Tags: php, encoding, sqlite, yii

I'm a newbie in Yii. I've created sqlite DB, include it in Yii config. Later via gii, I've created access to this DB. I can see my DB table with it's rows, but russian characters are not visible. The same situation if I'm trying to create row with the help of web-interface generated with gii. English text shown fine. But if I connect to this DB via command line with sqlite3 and type SELECT command, I can see russian text fine!

How can I make russian visible? Maybe some bugs with encoding??

Backup of my Yii project [**is here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w54f2hnqw5mjs08/www.rar) with sqlite db in it!

P.S.
When I do like this:

```
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
Yii::app()->charset='cp1251';
Yii::app()->run();
```

Russian text is visible, but looks like not russian. Ex: *„Ґбпвм ­ҐЈаЁвпв/ ­Ј«Ё©бЄЁ© (Ќ®ў.®д.)*

At the same time if I change this text to another russian via gii interface - it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **character encoding** to `UTF8` in your `config.php` as follows:

```
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/ /data/testdrive.db',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```